# MongoDB system.user table alter to system.users_prod and going to retrive values it return below error when log with root user

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB system.user table alter into system.users_prod. Then going to retrieve values from that collection and it return below error. Logged as root user.

My db is "abc"

```
PRIMARY> show collections
product_descriptions
products
system.indexes
system.users
system.users_prod 

 PRIMARY> db.system.users_prod.find()
error: {
    "$err" : "not authorized for query on abc.system.users_prod",
    "code" : 13
}
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Collections named `system.*` is treated specially (see [System Collections](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/system-collections/)). It is reserved for internal use. You should not create a collection that begins with `system`.